# How to embed font file in html?

Tags: php, html

I created simple form to give input in `Preeti` font.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <center> <form>
        <label><b>Preeti : </b></label>
        <div class = "a"> <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input"> 
        </div>
        </form> </center>
      </html>
  </body>
```

I tried to embed `Preeti` font in css.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Preeti";
  src: url("fonts/preeti.eot");
  src: url("fonts/preeti.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("fonts/preeti.otf") format("opentype"), 
    url("fonts/preeti.svg") format("svg"), 
    url("fonts/preeti.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("fonts/preeti.woff") format("woff"), 
    url("fonts/preeti.woff2") format("woff2"); 
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
.a {
  font-family: Preeti ;
}
```

Layout of form is above.
[image]

But When I give input,It don't type in `Preeti` font,It still type in normal English text.I want input in `Preeti` font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work. Add this to your css file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Preeti';
  src: url('http://www.fontsaddict.com/fontface/preeti.TTF');
}
```

Comment: That's not embedded but simply referenced via an URL